# Partition a regular graph such the neighbors of each vertex are nearly evenly split

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $\Delta_0>0$ such that the following holds:
>
> If $G$ is a $\Delta$-regular graph with $\Delta\geq\Delta_0$, then there is a partition $V(G)=V_1 \cup V_2$ of the vertex set of $G$ such that every vertex of $G$ has between $(1-\epsilon)\Delta/2$ and $(1+\epsilon)\Delta/2$ many neighbors in each $V_i$.

I'm not sure how to start. Any hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Lovász local lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma)?